# Windows Active Directory backup to a file

Tags: active-directory, backup, replication, files, restore

How can i take a complete backup of windows Active Directory into a single file and is it possible to restore this AD backup to another server?

I cannot use active directory replication now, because of the connectivity issues.

Comment: Maybe you could explain in more depth the actual problem or scenario you're facing as I'm not seeing how restoring a DC to new hardware will resolve a replication problem. Can you provide more details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always have more than one domain controller to help avoid this!

Microsoft provides documentation for this task.  For recent versions, you can use the windows server backup tool to perform an unscheduled backup and then later a full restore: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753359(v=ws.10).aspx

You will want to read through the dozens of notes and cautions before you start.  I would also check DNS very carefully after.